# __getitem__ error in black jack project

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to write a blackjack game for an online class I'm taking.  I know that I'll have to introduce objects at some point, but right now I'm just trying to write the very basic code for operations within the object.  I also have only chemistry as my background, absolutely zero computer science background.

What I'm trying to do is to pull the value text value from the first entry in the tuple, then assign it a numerical value so I can start to compare scores, once I get to the point of creating players.  However, I get this error, and I don't fully know what it means...the code is also below.  Still a noob here, just trying to learn!

```
27 def value_of_card():
```

--->28     x = deal[0]
    29 
    30 print value_of_card()

TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

```
import random

suits = ['spades', 'hearts', 'clubs', 'diamonds']
ranks = ['ace', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']

def deal():
    deck = []
    for suit in suits:
        for rank in ranks:
            deck.append((rank, suit))
    random.shuffle(deck)
    print deck
    deal = deck[0]
    print deal
    for card in deck:
        if deal in deck:
            deck.remove(deal)
            return deck
    print deck
    print deal[0]

print deal()

def value_of_card(deal):
    return deal[0]    

print value_of_card(deal)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- You pass the function reference to `value_of_card`, instead of passing the value *returned* by that function.
- Your deal function does not return a card, but the deck of remaining cards. You should not `return deck`, but `return deal`
- The search (with `for` loop) for the card that you selected is not necessary: you took it from index 0, so just remove the card at index 0 (with `pop(0)`)

Here is the corrected script:

```
import random

suits = ['spades', 'hearts', 'clubs', 'diamonds']
ranks = ['ace', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']

def deal():
    deck = []
    for suit in suits:
        for rank in ranks:
            deck.append((rank, suit))
    random.shuffle(deck)
    # you don't need to search for the card. It is at index 0
    # grab, remove and return the card (not the deck) in one go:
    return deck.pop(0)

card = deal() # remember the dealt card
print card

def value_of_card(deal):
    return deal[0]

print value_of_card(card) # pass the remembered card
```

And here is how it could look if you made it more OOP:

```
import random

class Card:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.rank + ' of ' + self.suit

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        suits = ['spades', 'hearts', 'clubs', 'diamonds']
        ranks = ['ace', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
        self.__deck = [Card(rank, suit) for suit in suits for rank in ranks]

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.__deck)

    def deal(self):
        return self.__deck.pop()

# Create a deck of 52 cards
deck = Deck()

# Shuffle the deck
deck.shuffle()

# Pull a card from the deck
card = deck.deal()

# Show the card
print(card) # this calls the __repr__ method

# ..or only the rank:
print(card.rank)
```

Comment: Seems a bit of a waste in `deal` to produce an entire deck to just pop the first one (of course if you were to continiously re-deal from the deck - that's different)... might as well just do `card = random.choice(suits), random.choice(ranks)`

Comment: @JonClements, of course, but the OP has more plans with the deck then just draw one card. See the first words of his question. ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and the little bit of guidance!  I keep forgetting that when you create a function, that you have to call the function using a variable...doh!  Thank you, I was able to re-write some of my code lines to achieve what I was trying to do, it's starting to make more sense anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call your `deal` function in `value_of_card` function.
You should also change your functions names to be distinct, because now you have too many objects called `deal` which is really misleading and makes your code hard to read.